# Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/client/node_modules/.vite/deps_temp_9a28dca3'

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, vuejs3

I created a project with front and back end and want to run everything through a docker
here is my dockerfile

```html
FROM node:20-alpine

RUN mkdir /client && chown -R node:node /client WORKDIR /client USER node

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci RUN mkdir /client/node_modules/.vite && chown -R node:node /client/node_modules/.vite RUN chmod -R u+rw /client

COPY --chown=node:node . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```html
version: "3.4"
services:
  client:
    image: node:alpine
    container_name: client
    command: ["-c", "npm run dev"]
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    build: ./client
    user: "node"
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    working_dir: /client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/client
      - /client/node_modules/
    tty: true
```

displays an error when starting the docker

```html
client  |   VITE v5.0.7  ready in 535 ms
client  |
client  |   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:4000/
client  |   ➜  Network: http://172.18.0.2:4000/
client  |   ➜  press h + enter to show help
client  | Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/client/node_modules/.vite/deps_temp_9a28dca3'
client  |     at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1380:26)
client  |     at runOptimizeDeps (file:///client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:64816:10)
client  |     at file:///client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:64199:46
client  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

> client  |   VITE v5.0.7  ready in 535 ms
> client  |
> client  |   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:4000/
> client  |   ➜  Network: http://172.18.0.2:4000/
> client  |   ➜  press h + enter to show help
> client  | Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/client/node_modules/.vite/deps_temp_9a28dca3'
> client  |     at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1380:26)
> client  |     at runOptimizeDeps (file:///client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:64816:10)
> client  |     at file:///client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:64199:46
> client  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

works with windows

I expected the project to start and everything to work

Comment: You don't seem to be "using Docker" in any meaningful way here; you're using the unmodified `node` image to run source code that exists only on the host.  It's very easy to install Node directly, usually a one-liner through your host OS's package manager; could you directly `npm run dev`, without doing any of the setup described in this question?

Comment: Root-level directories in Linux are owned by the root user and for good reason. Don't create new ones, and **definitely** don't change their permissions the way the existing answer suggests. Put your code in `/usr/src/app` or some other standard location rather than adding them to `/`. You wouldn't put your app at `C:\myapp` on Windows would you?

Answer (score -4):

To resolve this issue, you can modify your Dockerfile and Docker Compose configuration to ensure proper permissions are set for the user within the container.

Here's an updated Dockerfile that sets appropriate permissions:

```
FROM node:20-alpine

RUN mkdir /client && chown -R node:node /client
WORKDIR /client
USER node

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci
RUN mkdir /client/node_modules/.vite && chown -R node:node /client/node_modules/.vite
RUN chmod -R u+rw /client

COPY --chown=node:node . .
```

And modify your docker-compose.yml to mount the volumes with proper permissions:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: client
    command: ["npm", "run", "dev"]
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - ./client:/client:delegated
      - /client/node_modules/
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

The changes made:

- Using context and dockerfile in docker-compose.yml to specify the Dockerfile location explicitly.
- Mounting the volumes with the delegated option in docker-compose.yml which allows better synchronization and performance between the host and container filesystem.

These adjustments should help in setting up proper permissions and might resolve the permission denied issue you're facing during the Vite build process within the Docker container. Adjust paths and configurations as needed for your specific setup.

Comment: This is your friendly reminder that [AI-generated content is not allowed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1). Also that is a terrible idea, the **correct** way to handle this is for the OP to not try to create a new root-level directory in the first place.